# Is Optional.orElseGet(false) worse performance-wise than Optional.orElse(false)?

Tags: java, jvm

Trying to figure out what the JVM (AdoptOpenJdk 1.8) is doing behind the scenes in this scenario. Imagine this is executed once per API request (e.g., via a filter):

```
public boolean blah() {
  return Optional.ofNullable(something()).orElseGet(() -> false);
}
```

What are the performance implications of using `orElseGet(() -> false)` instead of `orElse(false)`? My understanding is that the JVM will have one anonymous function in the heap in the case of `orElseGet(() -> false)` that would potentially be re-used for each request whereas I would expect `orElse(false)` to add a `false` primitive to the stack for each request.

I don't expect any performance difference to be detectable, so I am trying to understand what is actually happening behind the scenes in the JVM.

The motivation behind `orElseGet(() -> false)` instead of `orElse(false)` is to purge `orElse` from the code base entirely to avoid developers misusing it (e.g., for an expensive operation).

Comment: Why not just fix the misuses of `orElse(expensiveOperation())` instead of adding many new misuses of `orElseGet`?

Comment: Engineering best practices are rife with examples where we follow certain behaviors to avoid gotchas rather than relying on catching the misuses of something (e.g., the way Crockford's JS recommendations are to prevent things like running afoul of function hoisting gotchas). You are asserting my `orElseGet(() -> false` is a misuse without providing a rationale. If you have an answer to my question about what the JVM is doing behind the scenes, I would love to read it.

Comment: Regardless of what the JVM does in these situations, I think it's a bad choice using `orElseGet` everywhere. It's about readability, and the principle of least astonishment. I know I would auto-refactor `.orElseGet(() -> false)` to `.orElse(false)` every time I saw it. Rather than banning `orElse` all together, I think you should use tools (like inspections in the IDE, or SonarQube) to discover misuses of it.

Comment: I would be taking a serious look at why a method returns java.lang.Boolean rather than boolean.  If it’s returning null to indicate an error, it should be using primitive boolean as a return type and should be indicating an error by throwing an exception.

Comment: I agree with marstran here.  The rationale for why orElseGet is being misused is the same as why using lambdas anywhere a simple expression is sufficient would be a misuse of a lambda.  You wouldn’t write `IntSupplier supplier = () -> a + b; int sum = supplier.getAsInt();`.  It’s visual noise that makes the code slightly harder to read.

Comment: Can only second @VGR’s comment, you should fix that `Boolean` returning method. If you can’t fix it, just use `return Boolean.TRUE.equals(something());` or `return Objects.equals(something(), true);`, as the entire use of `Optional` here is a misuse…